# Call an update method for all instances of a class in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, oop, updates, sprite-kit

Lost in a sea of confusion, I really hope someone can help me here. This question regards how to use object oriented programming correctly, something I can't seem to do.

I am also sharing my train of thought, if anything seems flawed please tell me.

*WHAT I WANT TO DO:*

I am making a SpriteKit game, and like all games, there is logic that needs to be run every frame. As of now, the only way I can run something every frame is using my SKScene's update method.

A game has players, enemies, bullets, obstacles, collectibles, you name it. Each one needs to update every frame to handle the rapidly changing environment. lets take 'bullets' for example. I have a 'bullet' class in my game. The bullet has logic that needs to be run every frame. I have an 'update' method in my class to handle this logic, but I cannot find a good way to **run this method every frame for all the instances of bullet.**

I have attempted this many ways and all are hideous and inefficient. I have, on numerous occasions, misused to beauty of OOP to the point of sloppy code that barely achieves the task at hand.

I need something like an `updateAllBullets` method, but even if that existed, I would then need to run an `updateAllEnemies`, `updateAllItems`, and that wouldn't even handle the subclasses of those game objects. This leads me to believe that I am misguided in how I am making this game. I am really hoping someone can work with me to get an efficient system in place, even if it means redesigning everything. I am not asking for code, of course, as I have not even provided any (I can upon request if its relevant), but I am instead asking for OOP concepts that I should be using.

I will gladly clarify anything you have as fast as I can.
Cheers.

Comment: I don't think this is about OOP, but rather working with collections. You can either store logical groups of nodes in an Array or some other collection type when you create them and then iterate through them in your update method. Or you can use enumerateChildNodesWithName. I would think that the Array would be quicker as you'd not be iterating through all nodes checking for a given name. Depending on the scale of your game, the speed might not be significant enough to matter.

Comment: I'll bare that in mind. Any more tips on organizing your game objects in games?

Comment: Why not check out a SpriteKit game tutorial and take note of how the game manages it's various nodes? The submitted answer should be enough to move you forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the method `enumerateChildNodesWithName:` in your `-update:` loop?

For example, in my code, I am using

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"projectile" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if (node.position.x < 0 || node.position.x > self.frame.size.width || node.position.y > self.frame.size.height)
        {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
    }];
}
```

I just need to give each projectile (or bullet) the name "projectile", and using this I can control the behaviour each node of the name in each `-update:` call.

Comment: That would work up to a point, but here is the problem with it: I don't actually have access to the bullet class anymore. All I have access to is the spritenode itself. This would be problematic because within the enumeration, I couldn't check something like the amount of damage the bullet deals. Also, I would have to do this for every single class I have in one implementation file, which can get messy.

Comment: Why not? If the node belongs to the bullet class, and was initialised with the damage value, then you can surely check it. For eg.. (BulletNode*)node.damage

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know you could cast like that! There is still a few more things to work out but this is extremely helpful. Any tips for working with a lot of classes? (Otherwise I will be needing tens of enumeration blocks, could get sloppy)

Comment: Create an enumeration block for each type of node you have and create a separate method for handling the behaviour... I am afraid you will have to create separate enumeration blocks, i cant think of a better way. If you find a better method be sure to post it here.

Comment: Alright, I will! I'll handle it this way for now, and tinker with different ways to work with children to make this easier to pull off.